# Codeigniter 2: The requested URL was not found on this server (404) error. CI isn't routing the right way

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, routes, url-routing

This is one of the most repeated questions, but I did not get it and had to ask. I use CI 2. I removed index.php from URL by following steps:

1. In `config.php` I set

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

1. In `routes.php` I set

```
$route['default_controller'] = "InterviewController";
```

1. here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|robots\.txt|css|js|libraries/ckeditor|upload)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
addDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

1. I enabled `mod_rewrite` on the web server.

So in the `index()` method of `InterviewController`, I load the `addInterview.php` view. After that, it is being called `addInterview` as the default page of the site when I type just the domain name. Problem occurs when I press Save button on `addInterview` page which must call `saveInterview()` from `InterviewController`. But in this step I get `The requested URL was not found on this server (404) error`. `saveInterview()` even hasn't been called. But if I myself type domainname/index.php/InterviewController/saveInterview everything works. Seems like I removed `index.php` just from default page, but not from all pages of my site. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading slash could be causing your problem.

Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: answered your problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062142/why-codeigniter-show-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/41862237#41862237

Comment: I can confirm that Mike's answer is the solution to all those that have https and had issues with the index.php using Codeigniter. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 2):

try this...its Working for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Ur_Folder_Path/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Ur_Folder_Path/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I set apache just for 1 virtual host, so my app folder is document root of apache, so i don't need to have UR_Folder_Path before index.php

Answer (score 1):

edite your .htaccess file to>

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YOUR_CI_PROJECT_NAME/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I set apache just for 1 virtual host, so my app folder is document root of apache, so i don't need to have YOUR_CI_PROJECT_NAME before index.php