# Force HTTPS and remove index.php on CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

So I'm using this .htaccess script on my VPS but it doesn't work on the point where it should remove the index.php from the url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Force SSL
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
Options -Indexes
```

As I said everything is fine with the redirect but the when I want to open domain.com/projects it's not found error but if I add domain.com/index.php/projects everything is fine...

Comment: Do you have access to your VHost file? If so, check that your website has access to your SLL port.

Comment: It has access to the port.

Comment: do you get any speciffic error message or response code that could help us figure out what the problem is ?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /dev was not found on this server.

Just this :/ Everything works fine without the https redirect but when I add it - it just doesn't work... I also tried other codes but nothing changes....

Comment: How about this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492446/codeigniter-2-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server-404-error-ci-is

Answer (score 0):

In `application/config/config.php` change:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: It's changed since the start of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Check your VHost file, make sure it looks like

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\http"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and not like

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\http"
    ServerName localhost
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: yep it's without the port